# Natural broadening and the electric field produced by a decaying atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

To calculate the line profile due to natural broadening it is common to assume that a decaying atom produces an electric field of the form:
$$E(t)=E_0 e^{-t\gamma}\cos(\omega_0t)$$ 
as stated e.g. [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o7gPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=electric%20field%20of%20a%20decaying%20atom%20natural%20broadening&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNy5LEmqPQAhVhKsAKHXAsA5EQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=electric%20field%20of%20a%20decaying%20atom%20natural%20broadening&f=false) (link to Google Books).

Here is my problem, I thought that on decaying an atom would release a single photon not a continuous wave; so why can we assume this form of electric field and where does it come from?

Comment: You're right, and you can do the calculation without assuming the atom produces such an electric field - see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/443054/what-is-the-meaning-of-natural-line-broadening/445731#445731.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it is due to the wave-particle duality, where photons can exist as both a particle and a wave. In this case then, a single photon in itself also produces a wave (you can check out Young's experiment on proving wave-particle duality, where even a single electron proved to have created a wave). Hence, this electromagnetic wave induces an electric field, and therefore even with a single photon, an electric field can still be created.